# Rails 4 scope on HABTM association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope, has-and-belongs-to-many

I'm a rails newbie and I created a scope on a HABTM association, but I still think it looks unnatural, not elegant, so I think there must be a better way of doing it. Could anyone advise me if there is such better way? I've seen other posts where people have the same question ([Scope for Self-joining HABTM Association](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8501687/scope-for-self-joining-habtm-association)) with no answer...

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :roles, :join_table => :users_roles
end

class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users, :join_table => :users_roles
end

scope :by_role, lambda { |role_name| joins('join users_roles on users.id = users_roles.user_id').
                                    joins('join roles on users_roles.role_id = roles.id').
                                    where('roles.name = ?', role_name) }
```

Comment: read this please: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has-many-through-and-has-and-belongs-to-many

Answer (score 15, accepted):

try this. it is more optimized.

```
 scope :by_role,  ->(role) { joins(:roles).where(roles: { name: role }) }
```

Comment: Thank you, now that looks elegant.